# Concatenate pdf without flattening but preserve fields

Tags: pdf, itext, flatten

I am trying to fill a template pdf and add another pdf at the end.
I have no problem to add page to another pdf, but the problem is, when I do that, my fields are lost even if I don't use stamper.setFormFlattening(true).

Here my code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ForStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, ParseException {
        createContractWithMoreFile();
    }

    public static void createContractWithMoreFile()
            throws IOException, DocumentException, ParseException {

        String linkPDF = "resources/pdfs/User.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(linkPDF);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

        PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

        form.setField("Name", "Jhon");
        stamper.close();
        String out = "results/merged.pdf";

        List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfPdfFiles.add(baos.toByteArray());

        byte[] informativaPrivacy = getPdfByteArray("resources/pdfs/second.pdf");
        listOfPdfFiles.add(informativaPrivacy);

        concatenatePdfs(listOfPdfFiles, new File(out));

        baos.close();
        reader.close();

    }

    public static byte[] getPdfByteArray(String filePath) {
        File fileP = new File(filePath);
        byte[] result;
        try {
            result = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fileP);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void concatenatePdfs(List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        for (byte[] inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

And here the file that I am using

1. [User](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sPq_Q7-RIYBRtx3Fuou5eM1_AxvrCGI-)
2. [second](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EmyQB6ejK4s_HtiayfSfWbUD4m2URDEX)

And the output file that is not what I want :
[result file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lm55bjj97N5pfiaIC5ylyKDNkGo3bW6Q)

So why the output pdf lost my field? Without concatenation there is not the flattening.....

As you can see in my result file,there is not the field, so If you whant to see it again, I have to use adobe Acrobat , use -> View(Vista)-> Tools(Impostazioni)-> Create form (Prepara Modulo).
But If I do this and try to exit the pdf, Adobe ask me to save the pdf that it changed, and is not what I want.

[image: The result]

The output pdf that I want is here: 
[Output File That I want](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XUCrjjjdzKbQrOM164ER5mJPU0_XpTlm)
With the field that are lost in the result file
[image: OutputImage]

Comment: Based on what we can see in your code snippet, there is no reason why "flattening" would be "lost". We can't reproduce the problem because your code snippet is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). We can't solve problems that we can't reproduce.

Comment: what you need to be sscce?

Comment: As it says on http://sscce.org : a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. Something that we can download, compile, and execute on our own machines, and that reproduces the problem so that we can see with our own eyes that something is wrong.

Comment: In addition to the code you may also want to share the data, example PDFs with which the issue is reproducible. Sometimes issues occur only for specific documents.

Comment: I add all, you can test it now @BrunoLowagie

Comment: The question contains a contradiction: the OP wants to flatten fields, and then complains that the fields are gone. The OP wants to keep the fields, and then complains that the flattening is lost. That doesn't make sense: when you flatten a form, fields are lost; when you want to keep the fields, you shouldn't flatten the form. I think that the root cause of this problem is the misunderstanding about the concept of flattening. It is totally unclear which result the OP expects.

Comment: Are you sure you want to flatten the form, or do you want to make the field read-only? There's a huge difference!

Comment: It would be nice to switch to an English UI before taking screen shots of Adobe Acrobat to describe some functionality. Furthermore, not everyone has a full Adobe Acrobat to compare, so if you can produce your desired output with Adobe Acrobat, simply also share that file so that it is clear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I can't change the language of the adobe, for the document i share it =)

Comment: Ah, so you want to ***add a field***! (Your `OutputThatIWant.pdf` has an additional text field with field name "Jhon"...)

Comment: nono.....The OutputThatIWant.pdf do not only contains the field Jhon, but also the fields, like "Name", "Surname", "Email" "Telephone" that are not in the result file

Comment: That's what "additional" means. To list the differences between the source and the desired result in more detail: ***a)** The form field `Name` is shortened and moved between the label "Name" and the vertical bar. **b)** A label "Jhon" is added after that bar and **c)** a new field `Jhon` thereafter.* But your code attempts none of these changes. Instead you set the value of the field `Name` to "Jhon" and then remove all form fields by flattening. Thus my question: Do you really want those changes a), b), and c) which can be found in your `OutputThatIWant.pdf`?

Comment: The text field Jhon was a misprint, if you download it again, you will see that I removed it. Don't look at in where position are the field. The difference between the ouput file and what I want is only 1: in the output file there not the fields: "Name", "Surname", "Email" "Telephone", even if I remove             stamper.setFormFlattening(true); nothing change

Comment: @mkl any suggestions?

Comment: Cf. my answer... I hope this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno's answer originally assumed the `stamper.setFormFlattening(true)` call from the OP's original code indicated that the form should be flattened. As it turned out this was not the case, the fields were meant to remain.

Thus, Bruno removed the form flattening line and pointed out that the result now was editable, i.e. the form fields were present. But the OP still insisted that they were gone.

As it turns out, both were right, each in his or her own way. The difference: The form fields were present in the output as *widget annotations on the page* but the ***AcroForm*** form definition was gone.

To make an iText 5.5.x `PdfCopy` instance create an **AcroForm** form definition in the target document which contains the merged form fields of all the copied source documents, one has to **activate its *mergeFields* mode**!

If you wonder why this mode isn't active by default: It has a drawback, all source `PdfReader` objects must remain open until the target `PdfCopy` instance is closed which can result in a substantially larger memory footprint of the code.

To work in *mergeFields* mode, the OP's `concatenatePdfs` method

```java
void concatenatePdfs(List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
    document.open();
    for (byte[] inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        reader.close();
    }
    document.close();
}
```

has to be rewritten like this:

```java
void concatenatePdfs(List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
    copy.setMergeFields();
    document.open();
    List<PdfReader> pdfReaders = new ArrayList<>();
    for (byte[] inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
        copy.addDocument(reader);
        pdfReaders.add(reader);
    }
    document.close();
    pdfReaders.forEach(r -> r.close());
}
```

*([CopyWithField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/copy/CopyWithField.java#L81) method `concatenatePdfs`)*

As you see, the *mergeFields* mode is activated by `copy.setMergeFields()` and the source `PdfReader` instances are not closed immediately after adding to `copy` anymore but instead collected in `pdfReaders` and only closed after `copy` is closed (which implicitly is closed during `document.close()`).

Comment: I'm using the C# version of iText and this solution worked for me very well. Namely the 5.5.13 version of the iTextSharp nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

There were numerous errors in your code. For instance: you don't need `org.w3c.dom.Document`, you need `com.itextpdf.text.Document`; this error made that your code couldn't even be compiled.

I fixed the errors, and ended up with this SSCCE:

```
package sandbox.merge;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ForStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, ParseException {
        createContractWithMoreFile();
    }

    public static void createContractWithMoreFile()
            throws IOException, DocumentException, ParseException {

        String linkPDF = "resources/pdfs/User.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(linkPDF);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

        PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

        form.setField("Name", "Jhon");
        stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamper.close();
        String out = "results/merged.pdf";

        List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfPdfFiles.add(baos.toByteArray());

        byte[] informativaPrivacy = getPdfByteArray("resources/pdfs/second.pdf");
        listOfPdfFiles.add(informativaPrivacy);

        concatenatePdfs(listOfPdfFiles, new File(out));

        baos.close();
        reader.close();

    }

    public static byte[] getPdfByteArray(String filePath) {
        File fileP = new File(filePath);
        byte[] result;
        try {
            result = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fileP);
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void concatenatePdfs(List<byte[]> listOfPdfFiles, File outputFile) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        for (byte[] inFile : listOfPdfFiles) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

I could only reproduce the problem you mention by removing the following line:

```
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

That line is missing from your code, and explains why the form isn't flattened.

**Summarized:**

When you flatten the form, you have this:

[image]

Where once was the field `"Name"`, we see the value `"Jhon"`, but the field itself is gone: that is what flattening is about: you remove all the interactivity.

When you don't flatten the form, you have this:

[image]

The interactive field is still there, unflattened. It was filled out with the value `"Jhon"`.

The OP seems to want to flatten the form as in the first screen shot, and at the same time keep the field as in the second screen shot. That is a contradication. The OP should clarify what is expected if an answer is needed.

**iText versions**

By the way: I used iText 5.5.13 to test this. Please be aware that iText 5 is no longer supported unless you are a paid customer. The current version is iText 7.1.2, but in 7.1.2, the `PdfStamper` class no longer exists. Filling out forms and merging documents is done differently in iText 7.

Comment: Sorry but no, maybe you don't understand my question, stamper.setFormFlattening(true); remove all my fields, so is why I don't use it. I use your code but the merged.pdf do not contains my field, If you download my User pdf you can see there is 4 fields: Name, Surname, Email, telefon, that are lost in the merged.pdf.

Comment: I think you are the one who doesn't understand: flattening = removing all the fields. If you don't want to remove the fields, you have to remove the line `stamper.setFormFlattening(true);` but then your form won't be flattened. You have to make up your mind: do you want the end result to be flattened or not? If not, don't complain that "it doesn't flatten the fields." If you do want to flatten the form, don't complain that "the fields are gone!"

Comment: Sorry, I am not english and I'm not an expert as you with itext, but like I says and like the example that I used, if i remove stamper.setFormFlattening(true); the result is the same, and is not what I am looking for, what I want is an outputPdf like this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwbRm.png

Comment: Take a look at the screen shots. There is a clear difference between the two resulting PDF's. With form flattening, the interactivity is lost; without form flattening it is preserved. **The result is NOT the same!!!**

Comment: You simple remove stamper.setFormFlattening(true);? Is what I do but I have the same results... is very strange

Comment: I repeat: the screen shots show a clear difference between the flattened and the interactive version. If you use *the same code* and get *a different result*, then you should question if you are using the correct iText version (there are some unofficial versions that are really problematic).

Comment: I think that I am abusing your patience. I have attached an image to my post, I have trying to create a new project with only the itext 5.5.13 dependecies, but nothing.... the only way to see again my field is to manipulate the pdf with Adobe Acrobat, using -> View-> Tools-> prepare Module; but is not what I am looking for

Comment: I assume that "Prepara modulo" means "Create form." This means that you do not want to flatten the original form. Hence your question was misleading. You asked: *So why the output pdf lost the flattening?* But actually, you don't want to flatten the form. You want to keep it interactive? Could you please update your question so that it's more clear? Also: you might want to share a link to the resulting PDF. If you want me to look at the question, you'll have to wait until the day after tomorrow, because I'm on the road tonight and tomorrow. Maybe @mkl can help.

Comment: Very sorry, but Yes, what I don't want to flatten the original form because I want to keep it iteractive. I will update my question, very thanks, I attached the ouput pdf.